# YUI3 selector problem in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, yui, css-selectors

Y.one('form fieldset:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('hide');

in chrome, FF, opera this line works but in ie6-8 it throws an error 
'Y.one(...)' is null or not an object.

where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have to add the "selector-css3" module to your .use() statement if you want to use CSS3 selectors in browsers that don't support them natively.