# Jquery + Ajax: Variable undefined error on IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, liferay, yui

All of my code is working fine for all the browsers but IE8 where im getting a variable undefined error. Im using YUI3, Jquery and Ajax with Liferay 6.2, The variable (dataTable) is a datatable created via Alloy UI. here's the code, also for some reason IE8 is ignoring all the dom manipulation via YUI. Please note that all the code is inside a .JS file, i know that YUI code usually goes inside a .JSP file but why is working fine with all the browsers and not for IE8 ?

```
function loadSollicitudDataGrid(value)
{
xmlObject = loadXMLObject(value);
dataStore = loadDataStore(xmlObject,1);

YUI({ lang: 'ca-ES' }).use(
        'aui-node',
        'aui-datatable',
        'aui-pagination',
        'datatype-date',

        function(Y) {

            var truncate = function (o) {
                var trunc = '';
                if (o.value == "No") {
                 trunc = '';
                } else {
                    trunc = '<i class="icon-bolt icon-1x"></i>';
                }
                return trunc;
            };

            function formatDate(cell) {
                return Y.DataType.Date.format(new Date(cell.value), { format: '%d/%m/%Y' });
            }

            var nestedCols = [             
                {
                key:'DocumentIdTr',
                sortable: true
                },

                {
                key:'Titol',
                label:'Títol',
                sortable: true
                },

                {
                key:'Urgent',
                allowHTML: true,
                formatter: truncate,
                label:'Urgent'
                },

                {
                key:'Codi_Sollicitud',
                label: 'Codi Sol·licitud',
                sortable: true
                },

                {
                key:'Data_Alta',
                label: 'Data alta',
                sortable: true,
                formatter: formatDate
                }

            ];

            numDataTable = document.getElementById("myDataTable").childNodes.length;

            if (numDataTable > 0){
                dataTable.set('data', dataStore);
            } else {
                dataTable = new Y.DataTable (
                          {
                            columns: nestedCols,
                            data: dataStore,
                            plugins: [
                                  {fn: Y.Plugin.DataTableHighlight}
                            ],
                            rendered: true
                          }
                    ).render("#myDataTable");
            }

            //Control de Mensaje Alerta
            var alerta  = document.getElementById("myAlert");

            if (entradas.length <= 0){
                alerta.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                alerta.style.display = 'none';
            }

             //Añadimos clases a la tabla para poder customizarla//
             var nodeObject = Y.one('#myDataTable table');
             nodeObject.removeClass('table-table');
             nodeObject.addClass('table');
             nodeObject.addClass('mytable');
             nodeObject.addClass('table-hover');

             /*Asignamos id's a las columnas de las tablas*/
             var documentIdTr = Y.one('#myDataTable table thead tr th:nth-child(1)');
             var titol = Y.one('#myDataTable table thead tr th:nth-child(2)');
             var urgent = Y.one('#myDataTable table thead tr th:nth-child(3)');
             var codi_solicitud = Y.one('#myDataTable table thead tr th:nth-child(4)');
             var data_alta = Y.one('#myDataTable table thead tr th:nth-child(5)');
             documentIdTr.addClass('DocumentIdTr_col');
             titol.addClass('titol_col');
             urgent.addClass('urgent_col');
             codi_solicitud.addClass('codi_solicitud_col');
             data_alta.addClass('data_alta_col');

             dataTable.delegate('click',function(ev) {
                var target = ev.currentTarget, 
                //modelList = this.get('data'),
                columns = this.get('columns'),
                //cellIndex = Y.Node.getDOMNode(target).cellIndex,
                rid = target.get('id'),
                r1 = this.getRecord(rid);
                var selectedColumn = columns[0].key;   
                var selectedCell = r1.get(selectedColumn); 

                var petId = selectedCell;
                DWRUtil.setValue("frmConsulta:id",petId);
                document.getElementById("frmConsulta:botoConsulta").click();   

            },".table-cell",dataTable);


            function esVisible() {
                var num_page = document.getElementById("numResultsPage").value;
                var visible = false;

                if (num_page < entradas.length && entradas.length > 0) {
                    visible = true;
                }
                return visible;
            }

            new Y.Pagination(
                {
                    boundingBox: '#pagination',
                    circular:false,
                    contentBox:'#pagination .pagination-content',
                    page: 1,
                    visible: esVisible(),
                    on: {
                        changeRequest: function(event) {
                            dataTable.set('data', loadDataStore(xmlObject,event.state.page));
                        }
                    },
                    total:number_of_pages
                 }
                 ).render();



              Y.one('.pagination-content .pagination-control:first-child').setHTML('<div><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-1x"></i></div>');   
              Y.one('.pagination-content .pagination-control:last-child').setHTML('<div><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-1x"></i></div>');
              //Ocultamos paginaciï¿½n interna (1,2,3..etc)
              Y.all('.pagination-content li:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-last-of-type(n+2)').addClass('ocultar');
              ocultar = Y.all('.ocultar');
              ocultar.setStyle('display','none');
              prev = Y.one('.pagination-content li:first-child');
              next = Y.one('.pagination-content li:last-child');
              prev.setStyle('cursor','pointer');
              next.setStyle('cursor','pointer');                

          }
        );


return "";

}
```

Comment: This previous SO post might help: [YUI3 selector problem in ie8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713263/yui3-selector-problem-in-ie8).  Seems like the same issue.

Comment: Thanks @Robert but is not working, is this the right way to include the css3 module ?
YUI({ lang: 'ca-ES' }).use(
   'aui-node',
   'aui-datatable',
   'aui-pagination',
   'datatype-date',
   'aui-selector-css3',
   function(Y) {

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is WAY more simple as i thought. For some reason all the modern browsers (including IE9) don't have any problems when you initialize Alloy UI with :

```
YUI({ lang: 'ca-ES' }).use(
    'aui-node',
    'aui-datatable',
    'aui-pagination',
    'datatype-date',

    function(Y) {...
```

But IE8 (of course) will give you a series of really weird console errors and will make your widgets work bad if you dont use AUI insted of YUI, so that was it i replaced YUI by AUI in all the parts of my code and now is working fine in IE8 too. If somebody can give a proper explanation will be really appreciated since is hard for me to understand why IE8 is not ok with using YUI to initialize Alloy UI widgets or use YUI.